# Kestrel Server trucating Request.Host to just subdomain

Tags: asp.net, azure-app-service-plans, kestrel

The title says it all. I'm running asp core app in azure. I'm noticing that Request.Host only returns the subdomain portion.

Can't tell of this is an azure implementation issue or Kestrel or asp core.

For example the following controller running on [mysubdomain].azurewebsites.net

```
 [Route("busted")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Index()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict.Add("Request.Host", Request.Host);
        return dict;
    }
```

would return

{
   "Request.Host" : "mysubdomain"
}

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: I believe the issue was an azure configuration or something because the issue has resolved this morning without code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was an azure configuration or something because the issue has resolved this morning without code changes.